# Use date picker range as a filter in a MDX query

Tags: filter, datepicker, mdx, iccube-reporting

I created a report against the demo Sales cube.
It includes a date picker with range (from & to) where the "on selection" event is named date window.
& a pivot table with a `MDX` query similar to this:

```
SELECT 
        [Time].[Calendar].[Day].[7 Jan 2005]
      : 
        [Time].[Calendar].[Day].[10 Jan 2005] ON 0
FROM [Sales];
```

I would like to replace the fixed dates in the query by the from and to in the date picker. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned above, IcCube Date Picker widget returns valid MDX value for range. Here is [demo report](http://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FRange%20filter%20demo&menu=on&ic3demo) with described configuration.

For more details check Date Picker's settings and Pivot Table's mdx settings.

Comment: i need a login for that demo!

Comment: @whytheq I fixed the link

Comment: if I change the date picker nothing happens to the mdx

Comment: @whytheq
(1) Change bottom input
(2) Table's content changed
(3) Represents real-time MDX value for Table
(4) Just a static value that should be used in table's config

http://storage6.static.itmages.com/i/17/0420/h_1492672654_6083889_1e02c2e142.png

Answer (score 2):

In many dialects of `mdx` if you have a parameter called `@aDate` and let us assume its current value is `7 Jan 2005` then you can add to `mdx` via the `strToMember` function like this:

```
strToMember('[Time].[Calendar].[Day].[' + @aDate + ']')
```

Or the `strToSet` function like this:

```
strToSet('[Time].[Calendar].[Day].[' + @aDate + ']:[Time].[Calendar].[Day].[' + @aSECONDDate + ']')
```

Answer (score 2):

In icCube I'd rather use MDX function [LookupByKey](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/LookupByKey.php) instead of [strToMember](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/StrToMember.php). Besides the better typing the compiler can easily guess the hierarchy that is handy in a few scenarios. IMHO, try never using StrToMember. Something like :

```
 [Calendar].[Day].lookupByKey( StringToDate(@date,"d/M/yyyy") )
```

To parse strings into dates you've a few functions available ( [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Java%20Functions.php) and [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Excel%20Date%20Functions.php) ).

I think the range filter directly returns the MDX range expression in the event directly (contact us directly if it's not the case).

Comment: (upped) I'm jealous of all those functions you provide to play with!! Wish MS was as active (or just a bit active!) when it comes to their offering and implementation of mdx